# Cannot use autodoxygen more than 1 time

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

I cannot use `autodoxygenfile` more than once in a single markdown file or in multiple files.

My project structure is as like as follows:

```bash
project/include/color/a.h
                /shape/b.h

project/doc/conf.py
```

I would like to use `autodoxygenfile` to fetch the comments, which are written using Doxygen style.

I have tried to use the following snippets in a markdown file, named `test.md`:

````bash
(section_sample)=

# Sample CPP

```{eval-rst}
.. autodoxygenfile:: a.h
   :project: auto
```
### Check shape files

```{eval-rst}
.. autodoxygenfile:: b.h
   :project: auto
```
````

In config file I have added by following [**this source**](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#confval-breathe_projects_source):

```py
# Here I know the relative path compared to conf.py that's why used ..
breathe_projects_source = {
     "auto" : ( "../include", ["color/a.h"] ,["shape/b.h"] )
     }
```

In `index.md` I have added the following:

````bash
(section_Intro)=

# Introduction

```{toctree}
:maxdepth: 1

markdown_files/test
```
````

While I am trying to build sphinx, it is showing error that it cannot find `a.h` file. I have separated the content of `test.md` file in two markdown files but same result. If I omit the usage of any of the `autodoxygenfile` it works finely. What could be the possible case for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. syntax error:

```py
breathe_projects_source = {
     "auto" : ( "../include", ["color/a.h" ,"shape/b.h"] )
     }
```